# Dynamically update one parameter based on the value of another

Tags: sql-server, reporting, reportingservices-2005

We have a report in SSRS 2005, where in we wanted to update one parameter(which is not linked to any other report parameters or dataset) based on the value of another report parameter(which is the selected value from a dataset). Can anyone let me know how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: So, from the comments below, it sounds like what you're really trying to do is to filter the options in the dropdown list for on field on the value entered in another field.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds wrong.  If you have parameter A that is selected from a drop down, and parameter B that is typed in, you want to change B to f(A,B)?  Instead, write your query to calculate f(A,B) and use that value.

Comment: My requirement is something as follows: I have got a parameter field 1 which will get its list populated from DB. I have got parameter field 2 which needs to be a textbox( and not a dropdown list) where in the user will enter the search criteria (say for simplifying the list of names getting populated in parameter 3 and no calculation is required). Now when I change a value in parameter field 1 will my parameter field 2 value get its value reset to default value? If I can reset the parameter value somewhere, please let me know the appropriate place to do. I am not sure if this is achievable.

Comment: I can't envision this scenario.  Perhaps you could give a concrete example?

Comment: I have param1 which will list all Emp Id from DB. Param2 is a search field which will be a text box. Say for an example the user can key in as "John" in param2. Param2 will serve as one of the input parameter for param3. So when user attempts to click on param3 it will display names starting with John. To reduce the list of names getting displayed in param3 we have introduced param2 (search field). Param3 takes both Param1 and Param2 as input. So when user changes a value in Param1 can I get param2 to be reset to empty or blank wherein Param2 is no where related to param1.

Comment: Jeremy

Thanks for your time and confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create a report parameter field that is filtered based on another parameter, create a report that produces the list of desired values.  Make the values in the report be links to another report where the selected value is passed in as a new report parameter.

Or, depending on your situation, it may be better to do the same sort of thing as a web page.  Create a page to let the user filter and select the desired values for the parameters, then pass them in to the report.